# C++ Passing pointer constant as parameter from main to method

Tags: c++, string, pointers, initialization, argument-passing

I am attempting to initialize variables within my object, using a function with const pointers as parameters.

I keep getting errors in many of the ways i attempted, here is my code:

```
class Molecule
{
   private:
    char s[21];
    char d[21];
    double w= 0;

   public:
    Molecule();
    void set(const char*, const char*, double);
    void display() const;
};

int main() {
    int n;

    cout << "Molecular Information\n";
    cout << "=====================" << endl;

    cout << "Number of Molecules : ";
    cin >> n;

    Molecule *molecule = new Molecule[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char symbol[21];
        char description[21];
        double weight;

       molecule[i].set(&symbol,&discription,weight);
      //...
   }
   //implementation of class

   #include "Molecule.h"
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cstring>

   void Molecule::set(const char*, const char*, double)
   {

    s = &symbol;
    d = &discription;
    w = &weigth;
   }
```

My question is: How would i correctly call the member function from an array of objects, using constant chars as parameter, and what is the correct way to set them to my variables in my class.

P.S: I have been trying to figure this out for a long time, and posting here is a last resort.

Comment: There's a lot of problems with this code.  Even if you fix the call like @simonc's answer, the member function itself is broken.  You'd need to copy out the strings, not simply assign (which will actually compile error, since you can't assign a pointer to an array.)  Is there a reason you're not using `std::string`?

Comment: To be honest with you, I am a beginner with C++, with little c experience. I have been restlessly studying concepts, however implementing them usefully is something i have difficulty with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code

1. `&symbol` (where `symbol` is `char[21]`) yields `char(*)[21]`, use `symbol` directly and let it decay to `char*` or use explicitly `&symbol[0]`
2. `double weight;` is uninitialized local variable, using it results in *undefined behavior* - you should initialize it: `double weight = 0.0;`
3. `double w= 0;` used to declare a member of `class Molecule` is invalid, you could use constructor's initializer list:

   ```
   Molecule() : w(0.0) { } // initializes `w` to `0.0`
   ```
4. `s = symbol;` where `s` is `char[21]` and `symbol` is `char*` will not copy strings, for C-style copying `strcpy` could be used (note that C and C++ are different languages)
5. you have called `new[]` so it would be nice and appropriate to call `delete[]` as well and instead of relying on OS cleaning it up after the program terminates: (otherwise follow the point 6)

   ```
   Molecule *molecule = new Molecule[n];
   ...
   delete[] molecule;
   ```
6. If you are allowed to use vectors, replace `Molecule *molecule = new Molecule[n];` with `std::vector<Molecule> molecules(n);`
7. If you are allowed to use `std::string`<sup>1)</sup> objects, replace `char[21]` / `char*` with `std::string` objects

Other suggestions:

- use meaningful names for variables, if you want to explicitly distinguish private members from other local variables, good convention is to use `_` at the end of the name:

  ```
  class Molecule {
  private:
      std::string symbol_;
      std::string description_;
      double weight_;
  ```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Basically what you need to know about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is that it is a template that wraps raw `char*` and it already contains well-defined copying, concatenation using operator `+` and most important: you don't need to bother with memory management. Just `#include <string>`

Comment: Thank you very much for the throughout explanation, after a brief research, i will learn vectors and use them. one more thing please, what is the topic of std::string, like how can i find out more on using it? Thank you

Comment: Thank you! btw this is a school assignment, and memory management is a requirement :(.

Answer (score 1):

In the call

```
 molecule[i].set(&symbol,&discription,weight);
```

you are passing a pointer to a `char` array.  This does not match the `char*` that `set` expects.

The easiest/best fix is to change this to

```
 molecule[i].set(symbol,description,weight);
```

relying on the `symbol` and `description` `char` arrays automatically decaying to pointers.

Alternatively, you could also write

```
 molecule[i].set(&symbol[0],&description[0],weight);
```

to explicitly pass `char*`

[Note that there are many other errors in the code posted.  Based on the question, I'm guessing they are just typos.  Please update your question if you'd like more info onn any of the other errors.]

Comment: Thank you very much for the throughout explanation, after a brief research, i will learn vectors and use them. one more thing please, what is the topic of std::string, like how can i find out more on using it? Thank you.

Comment: @user3258542 The first hit googling for [std::string tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html) looks like a decent overview